# installing Jupyter on server without internet access

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter

I need to install Jupyter on server, that does not have access to internet. I installed Ipython but to install Jupyter, I think it needs to have internet connection. Any solution for the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pip download jupyter` on your local machine to download all the required packages. Place them in a directory on your server. Use `pip install --no-index --find-links <directory> jupyter` on the server.

See [pip download documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/#overview) for more information.